# xsl select distinct on a created xml tree

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following xml tree.

```
<columns>
    <column>
        <name>Version</name>
        <type>string</type>
        <multiquery useconnectionid="1" get="Version">SELECT ...</multiquery>
        <columns>
            <column>
                <name>Success</name>
                <type>number</type>
                <query useconnectionid="2" param="version">SELECT ...</query>
            </column>
            <column>
                <name>Failure</name>
                <type>number</type>
                <query useconnectionid="1" param="version">SELECT ...</query>
            </column>
        </columns>
    </column>
</columns>
```

And the following xslt template:

```
<xsl:template match="column" mode="findid">
    <xsl:param name="header" required="yes" />
    <xsl:param name="dbid" required="no" />
    <xsl:variable name="dbids">
        <xsl:if test="$dbid">
            <xsl:value-of select="$dbid" />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:for-each select="multiquery">
            <id><xsl:value-of select="@useconnectionid" /></id>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="query">
            <id><xsl:value-of select="@useconnectionid" /></id>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values($dbids/id)">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="columns/column">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="columns/column" mode="findid">
                <xsl:with-param name="header" select="$header" />
                <xsl:with-param name="dbid" select="$dbids" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>

        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

For some reason I cannot get the created id tree to select distinct. It always plots 121 and I only want it to plot 12. I wan't a unique id list that I will alter call in the otherwise tree to write information. I ahve tried some of the methods used with xslt 1 but I think this is a problem as it's not there in the original xml file but I build a new tree that I try to sort distinct.

Any help or hints what I can try would be appreciated. I am parsing this with the saxon parser now.

// Andreas

edit:
I want to use the sorted id list to create connections from the header. So I create a setup for connection 1 and one for connection 2. The issue I have now is that I create connection 1 2 times as I cannot select distinct id:s.

Comment: Consider to post a sample of the output that you want to create for the input sample you posted, then we can suggest an XSLT 2.0 way of achieving that. If you want us the fix the posted XSLT then please provide a complete enough sample to run your code. Currently with a required param `header` but no sample of applying the template and passing in a param value it is difficult to tell what you want to happen.

Comment: Sorry about the bad format of the header but I can't add it as code in my original message or in this comment.

<header>
     <connections>
      <connection type="database" id="1">
       <host>192.168.0.100</host>
       <username>root</username>
       <password>pass</password>
       <database>test1</database>
      </connection>
      <connection type="database" id="2">
       <host>192.168.0.200</host>
       <username>user</username>
       <password>pass</password>
       <database>test2</database>
      </connection>
     </connections>
    </header>

Comment: So, you want to group your query elements by using @useconnectionid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about the confusion. It worked as I had it but the recursion made it look like the group by didn't work.

So the issue was that the recursion made it look like it printed the same 3 times.